# Masking a grayscale Image with a 2D Gaussian Mask fails

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

This seems fairly simple, yet I am not getting the desired result. Can someone please explain to me why? I have the code below to generate a 2D Gaussian mask with the mean at the center and sigma as 1/3 of the image height for a 32x32 pixel image as follows:

```
def gauss2D(image):
    x,y = image.shape[:2]
    shape = (x,y)
    sigma = 1/3 * min(x,y)
    m,n = [(ss-1.)/2. for ss in shape]
    y,x = np.ogrid[-m:m+1,-n:n+1]
    h = np.exp( -(x*x + y*y) / (2.*sigma*sigma) )
    h[ h < np.finfo(h.dtype).eps*h.max() ] = 0
    h = h / h.max() 
    return h
```

The following is the masking image I want to use :

[image]

The code I use to mask the image is as follows:

```
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
msk = gauss2D(gray)
masked_data = gray * msk
```

And the resulting image is this:

[image]

A blank white image, sometimes a few pieces in the corners show through for some different images.

I also tried a bitwise AND to apply the mask but I keep getting this error that I can't seem to fix:

```
res = cv2.bitwise_and(gray, gray, mask = msk)
```

cv2.error: OpenCV(3.4.1) /Users/travis/build/skvark/opencv-python/opencv/modules/core/src/arithm.cpp:241: error: (-215) (mtype == 0 || mtype == 1) && _mask.sameSize(*psrc1) in function binary_op

Comment: `msk` is an array of floats between 0 and 1?

Comment: Yes msk is an array of floats between 0 and 1. @MarkSetchell

Answer (score 0):

Try this, It works for me.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as st

def gkern(kernlen=21, nsig=3):

"""Returns a 2D Gaussian kernel array."""

interval = (2*nsig+1.)/(kernlen)
x = np.linspace(-nsig-interval/2., nsig+interval/2., kernlen+1)
kern1d = np.diff(st.norm.cdf(x))
kernel_raw = np.sqrt(np.outer(kern1d, kern1d))
kernel = kernel_raw/kernel_raw.sum()
return kernel
```

Input :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.imshow(gkern(21), interpolation='none')
```